# How to photograph glitter and holographic glitter?

Tags: lighting, macro, product-photography

I need to take pictures of glittery items, and some of the items also have glitter that gives a rainbow holographic effect.

When I take pictures using my DSLR the glitter always looks really flat and dull and there is hardly any holographic effect at all.

I do have a lightbox and macro / standard lenses for my DSLR. What setup can I use to best capture the sparkle?

Answer (score 3):

A couple ideas:

Glitter looks good because it's sharp and sparkly, you might try stacking two exposures: one with the softbox to get the object's shape and general character and another with a hard/point light source punch up the sparkles.

Without stacking, try a longer exposure where you move a light source across an arc to bring up the sparkle highlights.

A little on the cheesy 1970's kitsch side, but try a star filter.  Maybe combined with the stacking.